# Open a EEG EDF file using mne python

Tags: mne-python, european-data-format

I need to use mne python for my master degree project, but i'm new in python programming. So i'm trying to open a single EEG edf file, i have tried several codes and none of them worked. The last code i tried:

```py
import mne
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount ('/gdrive')
cd /gdrive/drive/MyDrive/EDFfiles
fname = 'chb01_01.edf'
raw = mne.io.read_raw_edf(fname, preload=True)
```

### and i get this message:
Extracting EDF parameters from /content/chb01_01.edf...
EDF file detected

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 raw = mne.io.read_raw_edf(fname, preload=True)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mne/io/edf/edf.py in read_raw_edf(input_fname, eog, misc, stim_channel, exclude, infer_types, preload, verbose)
1331     return RawEDF(input_fname=input_fname, eog=eog, misc=misc,
1332                   stim_channel=stim_channel, exclude=exclude,
-> 1333                   infer_types=infer_types, preload=preload, verbose=verbose)
1334
1335

in **init**(self, input_fname, eog, misc, stim_channel, exclude, infer_types, preload, verbose)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mne/io/edf/edf.py in **init**(self, input_fname, eog, misc, stim_channel, exclude, infer_types, preload, verbose)
132         info, edf_info, orig_units = _get_info(input_fname, stim_channel, eog,
133                                                misc, exclude, infer_types,
--> 134                                                preload)
135         logger.info('Creating raw.info structure...')
136

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mne/io/edf/edf.py in _get_info(fname, stim_channel, eog, misc, exclude, infer_types, preload)
374     misc = misc if misc is not None else []
375
--> 376     edf_info, orig_units = _read_header(fname, exclude, infer_types)
377
378     # XXX: `tal_ch_names` to pass to `_check_stim_channel` should be computed

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mne/io/edf/edf.py in _read_header(fname, exclude, infer_types)
361     logger.info('%s file detected' % ext.upper())
362     if ext in ('bdf', 'edf'):
--> 363         return _read_edf_header(fname, exclude, infer_types)
364     elif ext == 'gdf':
365         return _read_gdf_header(fname, exclude), None

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mne/io/edf/edf.py in _read_edf_header(fname, exclude, infer_types)
578     edf_info = {'events': []}
579
--> 580     with open(fname, 'rb') as fid:
581
582         fid.read(8)  # version (unused here)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/chb01_01.edf'

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion:
Firstly try to insert 'chb01_01.edf' in python working directory. Python will find the file or c:\temp_edf\chb01_01.edf. It is easier to find.
best

Answer (score 0):

To open a `edf` `eeg` file using Python,

```
import mne

raw =mne.read_raw_edf('')
```

place the path to your `edf` file in `singlequotes`.

This will read your entire `edf`. also,
raw.info
will give you the entire details of your file.